# mySQL Syntax Error on Constraint

Tags: mysql, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE MARINA_SLIP
(
SLIP_ID VARCHAR(4),
MARINA_NUM VARCHAR(4),
SLIP_NUM VARCHAR(4),
LENGTH INT,
RENTAL_FEE DECIMAL(8,2),
BOAT_NAME VARCHAR(50),
BOAT_TYPE VARCHAR(50),
OWNER_NUM VARCHAR(4),
CONSTRAINT MARINA_SLIP_SLIP_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (SLIP_ID),
CONSTRAINT MARINA_SLIP_MARINA_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (MARINA_NUM),
CONSTRAINT MARINA_SLIP_OWNER_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (OWNER_NUM) REFERENCES OWNER (OWNER_NUM)
);
```

The error states:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>   CONSTRAINT MARINA_SLIP_OWNER_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (OWNER_NUM) REFERENCES OWNER (O' at line 12

Does anyone know why this won't work?

Edit: this was figured out for me, small mistake on not including a foreign key reference.

Comment: The first foreign key isnt referencing any column...

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh thank you for pointing that out.  I'm in a beginning SQL class, where essentially I copied the constraints, and the foreign key reference was pushed a line down.  Obvious mistake that I spent 30 minutes trying to figure out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

add `REFERENCES` to `CONSTRAINT MARINA_SLIP_MARINA_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (MARINA_NUM)`
for example
`CONSTRAINT MARINA_SLIP_MARINA_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (MARINA_NUM) REFERENCES OWNER (MARINA_NUM)`